# upload image in django form

Tags: python, django, error-handling, image-uploading

am uploading image , but its not working the function is :
in views

```
 def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })

    def handle_uploaded_file(f):
        with open('ranjeet.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)



    form is: 
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uform" id="userform">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="usubmit">
</form>
```

in settings :

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/images/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

i dont know where the file has been saved.

Comment: Which error do you get? Please post it.

Comment: Can you please post the error message.

Comment: it is not throwing ant error also

Comment: look at your project folder, if there is a folder named `media`, perhaps it's saved there

Comment: Did u got the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is while you are trying to open a destination. There you have provided **"ranjeet.txt"** which is a file. There you should provide the path of your harddisk/folder path, where you want to save your uploaded file.
Please try using this code:

```
destination = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'wb+')

for chunk in f.chunks(): //f is the file info passed to handle_file_upload(f)               
    destination.write(chunk)
destination.close()
```

Another issue I found in your code. in form action neither i found any url nor "."